# Getting referral link with asp.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, referrals

How am i supposed to know from which webpage the user came into my website.
Is there any way of reading such info with asp.NET?

I would like to store that info (referral link) into a cookie for later processing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referrer and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer.aspx. Bear in mind it is not completely foolproof.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

[Request.UrlReferrer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer.aspx)